# How to display a number in a number format

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7, number-formatting

This is what I have in my template.php file:

```
function twitter_count() {
    $pageID = 'TWITTERACCOUNT';
    $info = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=' . $pageID .'') );
    echo $info->followers_count;
}
```

And I have this to display the result within a block:

```
<?php echo number_format(twitter_count("TWITTERACCOUNT") ); ?>
```

This is the result:

```
36170
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php echo number_format(intval(twitter_count("TWITTERACCOUNT") ) ); ?>
```

Or

```
 <?php echo number_format(floatval(twitter_count("TWITTERACCOUNT") ) ); ?>
```

And also remove that echo from your function. Instead, do a return.

Comment: Any luck? I think what is happening is your echo in the function is printing it, and even though you are echoing it with number_format in the block, it is echoing on execution of the function directly to stdout, and number_format is receiving a null value, thus formatting null which results in a blank string.